# Varnish 3 to 4 upgrade config changes

Tags: varnish

Can anyone who actually understands what the upgrade document states do a how to or a straight modification of a popular vcl, so people who don't have as much experience and pretty much just use these default vcl files?

Here's one that I and a few of my friends use routinely:

https://github.com/ewanleith/Wordpress-Server-Configuration-Files/blob/master/default.vcl

Like where do I start if I want to use this thing with 4.0?

vcl_fetch needs to be renamed, will this work if I just rename it and add vcl version to the top?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes, you rename all your functions, and alter all of your calls to work with the new language syntax.

It might be easier to just write the vcl file from scratch, using what you know from the v3 version. However, it should be quite possible to just convert the VCL to v4, by going over your code, using the migration guide here:
http://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.0/whats-new/upgrading-4.1.html
Edit: 
I've since found this tool, which helps https://github.com/fgsch/varnish3to4
It's not a magic bullet, you will still need to convert, but it should help.

EditEdit: Added @Jay Huggins's updated link

Comment: Upgrading to Varnish 4.1 is now [here](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.0/whats-new/upgrading-4.1.html).