# I need to upgrade varnish 3 to 4 without losing cache

Tags: varnish

I would like to upgrade Varnish 3 to 4 but without losing old cache(varnish 3 cache)

Could someone please help with this?

I replaced the VCL file and tried to reload getting VCL syntax error.

Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected one of
    'acl', 'sub', 'backend', 'director', 'probe',  or 'import'
Found: 'vcl' at
('input' Line 2 Pos 1)
vcl 4.0;

#### -----

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed
Command failed with error code 106
varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 vcl.load failed

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are some changes in syntax that you will need to fix. There arehe c plenty of guides to migration such as this: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rewrite your VCL config, as Simon said. My answer here includes a fixed wiki link, and a tool that will help with 3-4 migration.

[Varnish 3 to 4 upgrade config changes](https://serverfault.com/questions/588282/varnish-3-to-4-upgrade-config-changes/642781#642781)